# Visual Studio 2017 unresolved symbol link error with NetCDF C++ 4.3.0 interface library compiled with Mingw64

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, g++, mingw-w64

## Problem

Using MSYS/Mingw64/g++, I've compiled a NetCDF4 C++ interface library. I want to use it in a Win_x64 Visual Studio 2017 (v141 compiler/linker) project but get linker errors and not sure where.

## Steps & Results

Downloaded the following:

1. Windows pre-built NetCDF C library:[netcdf_c_libs](ftp://ftp.unidata.ucar.edu/pub/netcdf/netCDF4.6.3-NC4-DAP-64.exe)
2. C++ Interface library: [netcdf-cxx4-4.3.0](https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf-cxx4/tree/4.3.0)

Using the bash script below, the library compiles with the bash script shown below with `make check` returning PASS 7/8 & 1 FAIL on tests (non-related issue).

## Goal

To successfully build and run [pres_temp_4D_wr.cpp](https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf-cxx4/blob/4.3.0/examples/pres_temp_4D_wr.cpp) in Visual Studio 2017.

## Relevant Q&A

[What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

It's too general. This problem is isolated.

## Code

```sh
#!/usr/bin/bash

# Return if command/pipeline returns error
set -e

export CC="gcc"
export CXX="g++"

### Linking netCDF C Library - netCDF4.6.3-NC4-DAP-64.exe
# Got test fails with CXXFLAGS: -mdll -O2

export CFLAGS="-I/c/lib/netCDF-4.6.3/include"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/c/lib/netCDF-4.6.3/include"
export CXXFLAGS="-I/c/lib/netCDF-4.6.3/include"
export LDFLAGS="-L/c/lib/netCDF-4.6.3/lib"

export NETCDF_DIR="/c/dev/netcdf-cxx4"
export BUILD_DIR="$NETCDF_DIR/build"
export RELEASE_DIR="/c/lib/netcdf-cxx-4.3.0"

echo $CC
echo $CXX
echo $CPPFLAGS
echo $CXXFLAGS
echo $LDFLAGS
echo $NETCDF_DIR
echo $BUILD_DIR

# Enter netcdf directory
cd $NETCDF_DIR

# Restting NC++ interface library. Using v4.3.0. https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf-cxx4
git reset --hard
git clean -fdx

## Not sure what this does... 
# just following git readme instructions to do this prior to configure
autoreconf -if

mkdir -p $BUILD_DIR
cd $BUILD_DIR

#### Configure & Compile ####

# Someone said put this in?
# --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32
# --enable-shared

../configure --prefix=$RELEASE_DIR 2>&1 | tee configure-output.log
mingw32-make -j4 2>&1 | tee make-output.log && mingw32-make install 2>&1 | tee make-install-output.log
mingw32-make check 2>&1 | tee make-check-output.log
```

### Visual Studio 2017 (v141) Linker options:

```
/OUT:"C:\Users\Robbie\Projects\netcdf-data-analysis\cpp-tdms-streamer\build\TDMS_Streamer\Debug-x64\TDMS_Streamer.exe" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"C:\Users\Robbie\Projects\netcdf-data-analysis\cpp-tdms-streamer\build\TDMS_Streamer\Debug-x64\TDMS_Streamer.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "szip.lib" "zlib.lib" "hdf5.lib" "hdf5_hl.lib" "hdf5_hl_cpp.lib" "netcdf.lib" "libnetcdf_c++4.a" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /DEBUG /MACHINE:X64 /INCREMENTAL /PGD:"C:\Users\Robbie\Projects\netcdf-data-analysis\cpp-tdms-streamer\build\TDMS_Streamer\Debug-x64\TDMS_Streamer.pgd" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"C:\Users\Robbie\Projects\netcdf-data-analysis\cpp-tdms-streamer\build\TDMS_Streamer\intermediates\Debug-x64\TDMS_Streamer.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /VERBOSE:Lib /LIBPATH:"C:\Users\Robbie\Projects\netcdf-data-analysis\cpp-tdms-streamer\lib\HDF5-1.10.5-win64\lib" /LIBPATH:"C:\Users\Robbie\Projects\netcdf-data-analysis\cpp-tdms-streamer\lib\netCDF-4.6.3\lib" /LIBPATH:"C:\lib\netcdf-cxx-4.3.0\lib" /LIBPATH:"C:\Users\Robbie\Projects\netcdf-data-analysis\cpp-tdms-streamer\lib\tdms-recording-lib" /LIBPATH:"C:\lib\boost\boost_1_68_0\stage\lib" /TLBID:1
```

## Linker error (1 of 13)

```
1>pres_temp_4D_wr.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 
"public: __cdecl netCDF::NcFile::NcFile(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,enum netCDF::NcFile::FileMode)" (??0NcFile@netCDF@@QEAA@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@W4FileMode@01@@Z) 
referenced in function main
```

Comment: You will need to either recompile C++ Interface library using Visual C++ or compile example .cpp using mingw. Consuming C++ libraries built with different compilers does not work cause of ABI and name mangling incompatibilities.

Comment: My compiler/linker knowledge is basic. How do I convert the makefile and/or configure scripts in the netcdf-cxx4 into something visual studio understands?